# Yet another "Why is this statement running slowly" inquiry

Tags: mysql

I've been reading similar questions to mine on SO and googling for days and can't seem to find a solution that works for my situation. Please see the details below. When I run the sql statement below, it takes over a minute. It also is not using the index on tableA.col4. Why?

Like I said, I have been googling for quite some time but seem to be running in circles at this point. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---THE DETAILS--- (Sorry it is soooo long, but better to have all the info, I guess)

I have the following two tables, table A and B:

tableA: (5M rows...will eventually be 20M)

```
tableA | CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `col1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `col2` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col3` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col5` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`),
  KEY `col4` (`col4`),
  KEY `col5` (`col5`),
  KEY `col1` (`col1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Indexes on tableA:

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tableA |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | col1         | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableA |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | col2         | A         |     4780162 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableA |          1 | col4       |            1 | col4         | A         |         426 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableA |          1 | col5       |            1 | col5         | A         |     2390081 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableA |          1 | col1       |            1 | col1         | A         |     2390081 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

tableB: (1M rows...will eventually be around 5M)

```
| tableB | CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `col1` varchar(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col2` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col5` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col6` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col7` varchar(300) DEFAULT '0',
  `col8` varchar(300) DEFAULT '0',
  `col9` varchar(300) DEFAULT '0',
  `col10` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col11` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col12` mediumtext,
  `col13` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col14` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col15` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col16` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col17` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col18` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col19` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col20` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col21` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col22` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col23` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`),
  KEY `col3` (`col3`),
  KEY `col5` (`col5`),
  KEY `col2` (`col2`),
  KEY `col1` (`col1`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `col12` (`col12`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Indexes on tableA:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tableB |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | col1           | A         |      989765 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableB |          1 | col3           |            1 | col3           | A         |        9799 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableB |          1 | col5           |            1 | col5           | A         |       98976 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableB |          1 | col2           |            1 | col2           | A         |      197953 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableB |          1 | col1           |            1 | col1           | A         |      989765 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tableB |          1 | col12          |            1 | col12          | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.col1 = tableB.col1 
WHERE tableA.col4 NOT IN ('8/G','2','9/D','7','6/M') ORDER BY tableA.col5 DESC LIMIT 25

+----+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableA   | ALL    | col4              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 4780162 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableB   | eq_ref | PRIMARY, col1     | PRIMARY | 902     | mydb.tableA.col1      |       1 |                             |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

PROFILING:

```
Status  Time
starting    0.000012
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000003
checking query cache for query  0.000079
checking permissions    0.000004
checking permissions    0.000003
Opening tables  0.000013
System lock 0.000006
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000027
init    0.000028
optimizing  0.000008
statistics  0.000404
preparing   0.000009
executing   0.000003
Sorting result  2.135376
Sending data    0.004359
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000004
Sending data    0.004735
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000004
....
....
....   
Sending data    0.008573
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000006
Sending data    0.005630
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000005
Sending data    0.005760
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000005
Sending data    0.005295
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000005
Sending data    0.005239
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000004
Sending data    0.004954
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000004
Sending data    82.246597
end 0.000012
query end   0.000004
closing tables  0.000009
freeing items   0.000014
logging slow query  0.000002
logging slow query  0.000003
cleaning up 0.000003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It also is not using the index on tableA.col4. Why?

Well, the tableA.col4 NOT IN ('8/G','2','9/D','7','6/M') is the culprit.  MySQL really can't use an index to satisfy a NOT IN.

What is happening is MySQL is running through all ~5 million rows of tableA and building up a set of rows where tableA.col4 NOT IN ('8/G','2','9/D','7','6/M').  Then it is sorting that set in descending order by col5 then (hopefully) picking the top 25 rows out of that and then performing the join.

It is possible that a multi-column index on col5 and col4 (in that order) on tableA will help this query because I believe MySQL will work the index in reverse order and will stop after it gets 25 rows that satisfy tableA.col4 NOT IN ('8/G','2','9/D','7','6/M').

So my suggestion would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tableA_col5_col4 ON tableA(col5,col4);
```

Then re-run your query.

Comment: Yes, your right about the reason it can't currently use the index - but I don't think it will use the index you suggest either

Comment: You may be right.  I wish MySQL would implement descending indexes.  It would help a lot of common queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation of why it isn't using my index. I tried your multi-column index but the query doesn't use that either....it was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Just doing a quick shoot. The profiling output says that Sending data takes 82.246597, so  maybe you get lots of output which takes lots of time to transfer?

Comment: "Sending data" naturally sounds like it should refer to using network bandwidth, but it turns out it refers to the work of moving data around in memory within the mysqld process.  E.g. from the storage engine to the SQL layer.